# C# Linq Where Date Between 2 Dates

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get my linq statement to get me all records between two dates, and I'm not quite sure what I need to change to get it to work: `(a.Start >= startDate && endDate)`

```
var appointmentNoShow =
    from a in appointments
    from p in properties
    from c in clients
    where a.Id == p.OID && (a.Start.Date >= startDate.Date && endDate)
```

Comment: [LINQ Between Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Just change it to

```
var appointmentNoShow = from a in appointments
                        from p in properties
                        from c in clients
                        where a.Id == p.OID && 
                       (a.Start.Date >= startDate.Date && a.Start.Date <= endDate)
```

Comment: Hi @Giorgi: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Hi @admin the solution for this is don't specify the function Date in the properties of the table. For example: db.Invoices.Where(w=>w.Date >= Date1.Date && w.Date <= Date2.Date).ToList(). It will work ;)

Comment: @user1502624 That doesn't work in EF mainline and I've seen the source code for that. I've made a branch that does work. It works by converting the `.Date` call to a `EntityFunctions.TruncateDate` call.

Comment: This query will omit appointments that start before the start date and end after the end date; multi-day appointments that should be included. If you need a query that includes such possibilities then take a look at the "second query" here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7815706/4040647 by @Enigmativity

Comment: In comparison, `DateTime.Date` cannot be converted to SQL. To get date part, `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) can be used.

Comment: For it to be a true 'between' the second conditional should be '<' and not '<=', unless you want to include midnight of the day after in both days if you happen to also query the next day later.  A true between in SQL is less than the end date.  Not less than or equal to.

Answer (score 30):

```
var appointmentNoShow = from a in appointments
                        from p in properties
                        from c in clients
                        where a.Id == p.OID
                        where a.Start.Date >= startDate.Date
                        where a.Start.Date <= endDate.Date
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var QueryNew = _context.Appointments.Include(x => x.Employee).Include(x => x.city).Where(x => x.CreatedOn >= FromDate).Where(x => x.CreatedOn <= ToDate).Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

So you are scrolling down because the Answers do not work:

This works like magic (but they say it has efficiency issues for big data, And you do not care just like me)

1- Data Type in Database is "datetime" and "nullable" in my case.

Example data format in DB is like:

```
2018-11-06 15:33:43.640
```

An in C# when converted to string is like:

```
2019-01-03 4:45:16 PM
```

So the format is :

```
yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt
```

2- So you need to prepare your datetime variables in the proper format first:

Example 1

```
yourDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Example 2 - Datetime range for the last 30 days

```
    DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
    DateTime dateEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
```

3- Finally the linq query you lost your day trying to find (Requires EF 6)

```
using System.Data.Entity;

_dbContext.Shipments.Where(s => (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Created_at.Value) >= dateStart && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.Created_at.Value) <= dateEnd)).Count();
```

To take time comparison into account as well :

```
(DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(s.Created_at.Value.Year, s.Created_at.Value.Month, s.Created_at.Value.Day, s.Created_at.Value.Hour, s.Created_at.Value.Minute, s.Created_at.Value.Second) >= dateStart && DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(s.Created_at.Value.Year, s.Created_at.Value.Month, s.Created_at.Value.Day, s.Created_at.Value.Hour, s.Created_at.Value.Minute, s.Created_at.Value.Second) <= dateEnd)
```

Note the following method mentioned on other stackoverflow questions and answers will not work correctly:

```
....
&&
(
    s.Created_at.Value.Day >= dateStart.Day && s.Created_at.Value.Day <= dateEnd.Day &&
    s.Created_at.Value.Month >= dateStart.Month && s.Created_at.Value.Month <= dateEnd.Month &&
    s.Created_at.Value.Year >= dateStart.Year && s.Created_at.Value.Year <= dateEnd.Year
)).count();
```

if the start day was in this month for example and the end day is on the next month, the query will return false and no results, for example:

DatabaseCreatedAtItemThatWeWant =  2018/12/05

startDate = 2018/12/01

EndDate = 2019/01/04

the query will always search for days between 01 and 04 without taking the "month" into account, so "s.Created_at.Value.Day <= dateEnd.Day" will fail

And in case you have really big data you would execute Native SQL Query rather than linq

```
...
    ... where Shipments.Created_at BETWEEN CAST(@Created_at_from as datetime) AND CAST(@Created_at_to as datetime))
    ....
```

Thanks

Comment: Still not getting correct items back in the range of dates.

Answer (score 3):

If someone interested to know how to work with 2 list and between dates

```
var newList = firstList.Where(s => secondList.Any(secL => s.Start > secL.RangeFrom && s.End < secL.RangeTo))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
 public List<tbltask> gettaskssdata(int? c, int? userid, string a, string StartDate, string EndDate, int? ProjectID, int? statusid)
        {
            List<tbltask> tbtask = new List<tbltask>();
            DateTime sdate = (StartDate != "") ? Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).Date : new DateTime();
            DateTime edate = (EndDate != "") ? Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).Date : new DateTime();
            tbtask = entity.tbltasks.Include(x => x.tblproject).Include(x => x.tbUser).
                Where(x => x.tblproject.company_id == c
                    && (ProjectID == 0 || ProjectID == x.tblproject.ProjectId)
                    && (statusid == 0 || statusid == x.tblstatu.StatusId)
                    && (a == "" || (x.TaskName.Contains(a) || x.tbUser.User_name.Contains(a)))
                    && ((StartDate == "" && EndDate == "") || ((x.StartDate >= sdate && x.EndDate <= edate)))).ToList();



            return tbtask;


        }
```

this my query for search records based on searchdata and between start to end date

Answer (score 2):

If you have date interval filter condition and you need to select all records which falls partly into this filter range. Assumption: records has ValidFrom and ValidTo property.

```
DateTime intervalDateFrom = new DateTime(1990, 01, 01);
DateTime intervalDateTo = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);

var itemsFiltered = allItems.Where(x=> 
    (x.ValidFrom >= intervalDateFrom && x.ValidFrom <= intervalDateTo) ||
    (x.ValidTo >= intervalDateFrom && x.ValidTo <= intervalDateTo) ||
    (intervalDateFrom >= x.ValidFrom && intervalDateFrom <= x.ValidTo) ||
    (intervalDateTo >= x.ValidFrom && intervalDateTo <= x.ValidTo)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem getting this to work.

I had two dates in a db line and I need to add them to a list for yesterday, today and tomorrow.

this is my solution:

```
        var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);            
        var vm = new Model()
        {
            Yesterday = _context.Table.Where(x => x.From <= yesterday && x.To >= yesterday).ToList(),
            Today = _context.Table.Where(x => x.From <= today & x.To >= today).ToList(),
            Tomorrow = _context.Table.Where(x => x.From <= tomorrow & x.To >= tomorrow).ToList()
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(StartDateTime)` To remove the time from datetime

```
var appointmentNoShow =
from a in appointments
from p in properties
from c in clients
where a.Id == p.OID && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Start) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) && endDate)
```