# Select records with specific timespan between datetime field with linq query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, datetime

I have a table with some records about my users and their login datetimes
so the table have userId and loginDateTime and other required columns.
The table is grouped by userIds.

I want to select logins that appears in specific timespan (for example in 2 hours) for each group (indeed each user).

For better illustration, the query must return logins about an specific user in defined timespane

For example the table is :

```
id     userId     loginDateTime
-----  ---------  -----------------------    
1      233        01/01/2015 1:04:22 PM
2      233        01/01/2015 2:01:43 PM
3      234        01/01/2015 1:04:12 PM
4      235        01/01/2015 8:22:54 PM
5      235        01/01/2015 1:51:53 PM
6      234        01/01/2015 12:07:32 PM
7      233        01/01/2015 1:09:18 PM
8      233        01/01/2015 4:14:02 PM
```

Result for user "233" and "1 hour timespan" must be like this

```
id     userId     loginDateTime
-----  ---------  ------------------------
1      233        01/01/2015 1:04:22 PM
2      233        01/01/2015 2:01:43 PM
7      233        01/01/2015 1:09:18 PM
```

I'm looking for SQL and the equivalent LINQ statements.

Comment: Did you actually search first? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815235/date-range-falling-between-two-dates-in-a-linq-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815235/date-range-falling-between-two-dates-in-a-linq-query)

Comment: You should probably start by looking at the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @stuartd this is not only code writing problem, my main question is lie beyond SQL concepts !!!

Comment: @markpsmith tnx for link but its not equals to my question. I want mention just a timespan, not an specific start and end datetime

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  DECLARE @userId AS INT
  DECLARE @timestamnp AS INT

  SET @userId = 233
  SET @timestamp = -1  --one hour ago from now

  SELECT id, userId, loginDateTime FROM myTable 
  WHERE @userId=233 AND loginDateTime>= DATEADD(hh, @timestamp, GETDATE())
```

More about [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: I thing your solution will return the timespan from now!

Answer (score 0):

My linq isn't that good, but you can start with something like this. You can also try using anonymous methods for your selects:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Logins");
  table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
  table.Columns.Add("userId", typeof(int));
  table.Columns.Add("loginDateTime", typeof(DateTime));
  table.Rows.Add(1, 233, new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 1, 04, 22));
  table.Rows.Add(2, 233, new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 2, 01, 43));
  table.Rows.Add(3, 234, new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 1, 04, 12));
  table.Rows.Add(4, 235, new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 8, 22, 54));

  IEnumerable<DataRow> linkQuery = from times 
                                   in table.AsEnumerable() 
                                   select times;

  List<DataRow> listOfTimes = new List<DataRow>();
  DateTime checkAgainst = linkQuery.ElementAt(1).Field<DateTime>("loginDateTime");
  foreach (DataRow row in linkQuery) 
  {
    TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan();
    DateTime checkedRow = row.Field<DateTime>("loginDateTime");
    span = checkAgainst - checkedRow;
    if (span.Hours == 0 && span.Minutes <= 59)
    {
      listOfTimes.Add(row);
    }
  }

  Console.ReadKey();
```

Also, you will probably want to modify your time span checking to make it more precise.