# Get records by columns date

Tags: entity-framework

I have start date and end date columns in my table.

I need to retrieve only the records from the table which today date is between start date and end date  of the record.

What is elegant way to implement it using LINQ to Entity?

Comment: What are you after? LINQ query or how to use EF?

Comment: Something like this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815235/date-range-falling-between-two-dates-in-a-linq-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815235/date-range-falling-between-two-dates-in-a-linq-query)