# How do i find values between two different dates in MVC3 using LINQ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In the controller i need to get the values of Datetime selected in the 2 textboxes and process those values against my database and pass the result to the view ..

Pls guide me how can i do this ..

Comment: perhaps this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237440/c-sharp-linq-where-date-between-2-dates

Comment: No ..,I have 2 textboxes for 2 date entries ..if i have 2 datetime values in 2 textboxes then i press submit button ..it automatically passes the value to the controller and process the values between 2 dates and returning the value in the same view..,

Comment: Show the code.. probably we can understand it better

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

**CSHTML**

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
...
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
...
</select>
```

**MVC**

```
public ActionResult Index(string select1, string select2)
{
    DateTime date1;
    DateTime date2;

    bool isDate1 = DateTime.TryParse(select1, out date1);
    bool isDate2 = DateTime.TryParse(select2, out date2);

    ... do some checking to see if both are valid dates

    var timeSpanBetweenDates = date1.Subtract(date2);

    ... call your DB
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for the timespan. It sounds like the link dan_l posted is what the OP is looking for.