# How to use Between keyword in LINQ

Tags: linq

What is the Syntax to use Between Keyword in LINQ? Is it possible to use BETWEEN keyword in LINQ?

Awaiting for the response.
Thanks

Comment: Between what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>=` and `<=`.

Look similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237440/c-sharp-linq-where-date-between-2-dates)

Comment: Yes, but it's a duplicate and your answer has no added value

Comment: @Tim Schmelter,                                                                                                     Can u please share the syntax for using BETWEEN keyword in Linq?

Comment: @MadhavaReddy: there is no between keyword in c#, use `>=` and `<=`