# How can I pass 2 date values in field expression

Tags: c#

I have been trying to pass 2 dates through field expression and i'm encountering an error. Please find my code below:

```
FilterExpression="PreparedDate >= 'id={0}' and PreparedDate <= 'id2{0}'"
```

I want to achieve the query:

```
select * from table where date between date1 and date2.
```

I have 2 controls with the date values.

The exception:

> [EvaluateException: Cannot perform '>=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.] System.Data.BinaryNode.SetTypeMismatchError(Int32 op, Type left, Type right) +26
>
> System.Data.BinaryNode.BinaryCompare(Object vLeft, Object vRight, StorageType resultType, Int32 op, CompareInfo comparer) +2133
>
> System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left, ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[] recordNos) +11692
>
> System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version) +26

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237440/c-sharp-linq-where-date-between-2-dates

Comment: sure it's `id={0}` and not `id1{0}`?

Comment: what type of error, and what is the error message?

Comment: [EvaluateException: Cannot perform '>=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.]
   System.Data.BinaryNode.SetTypeMismatchError(Int32 op, Type left, Type right) +26
   System.Data.BinaryNode.BinaryCompare(Object vLeft, Object vRight, StorageType resultType, Int32 op, CompareInfo comparer) +2133
   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left, ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[] recordNos) +11692
   System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version) +26

Comment: Try `FilterExpression=string.Format("PreparedDate >= '{0}' and PreparedDate <= '{1}'", id, id2)`.  I'm not sure how you are using those braced indexes.  This is just a guess.

Comment: you need to convert the strings to datetime objects using DateTime.Parse first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Filter expression was wrong.

This is the correct code:

FilterExpression="preparedDate >= '{0}' and preparedDate <= '{1}'"

Thank you all...