# C# lambda with datetime and between

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I am using a versioned table and i would like to get the history of a particular row. I can do the query in `Sql` but I am having an issue writing using a lambda expression.

```
SELECT * FROM indexes.folder   
FOR SYSTEM_TIME    
BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000'   
WHERE id = 27918 ORDER BY ValidFrom;
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237440/c-sharp-linq-where-date-between-2-dates

Comment: If you select by WHERE id = 27918 then is there anything left to order? What is this? So confusing.

Comment: @Avin It might be a poorly named foreign key (I hope?). If not, I'm with you on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Linq Where Date Between 2 Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237440/c-sharp-linq-where-date-between-2-dates)

Comment: its not a foreign key . I am using a versioned table so i want to get the history of  the FolderId

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Where()` to filter data and `OrderBy()`:

```
var id = 27918;
var result = data.Where(i => i.SystemTime >= new DateTime(2014, 1, 1) &&
                             i.SystemTime <= new DateTime(2020, 1, 1) &&
                             i.Id == id)
                 .OrderBy(i => i.ValidFrom);
```

Comment: when i try that query i get an error saying Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type bool and int.

Comment: @GreatKhan2016, see edit - it should be `==` instead of `=`

Comment: where does the systemTime property come from ? Do i have to add it into my class ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
folders.Where(f => f.SystemTime >= beginTime && f.SystemTime <= endTime);
```

Comment: You're also missing half of the query

Comment: Ugh. Wrong overload.

Comment: @Sayse the question was about the datetime, not about the rest of the query.

Comment: @Bas It might still be worth adding it for completeness.

Comment: "Does anyone know a way of writing this with a lamba expression" would suggest otherwise.

Comment: I'm going by the title. Also writing the rest of the query would require assumptions on my part about how his data is structured. Therefore, I figured it would be wise to only focus on the subject of his question, namely how to do an SQL BETWEEN in a lambda expression.

Comment: If you need to rely on such assumptions in order to answer a question then that would imply that the question isn't answerable without updates from the OP.

Comment: Not if the question is specifically about the datetime part of the query, as his title suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Versioned Tables are not support in Entity framework yet so i wrote a raw SQL query.