# "Between" in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ Between Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator)

Dear All,
Hi,
I need to write this query in LINQ C#. can anyone help me?

```
Select *  
From Mytable  
where MyText BETWEEN 'john' AND 'Pear'
```

Comment: Did you tried http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&q=linq+between&aq=0&aqi=g10&oq=linq+be&fp=c5aa4278f68e4a4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this query should work:

```
var results = yourTable.Where(x => x.Text.CompareTo("john") > 0 && 
                                   x.Text.CompareTo("Pear") < 0);
```

This assumes that you want to compare the text in each row of the table, and not some pre-dfined string.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it with ObjectQuery

```
MytableSet.Where("it.Name between @start and @end", new ObjectParameter("start", "john"), new ObjectParameter("end", "Pear"))
```

**EDIT:**

Forget to mention that this statement is specific to Entity Framework not LINQ2SQL.