# Linq2SQL Where Between

Tags: linq-to-sql, between

Is is possible to do this in SQL in Linq to SQL?

```
Select field from table where date between '2010-01-01' and '2010-01-31';
```

I realize I could do:

```
where (monthBeginDate < a.StopDateActual && a.StopDateActual < monthEndDate)
```

But I was curious if I could do the former. I have a bad habit of screwing up the less than and greater than on statements like that.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator

Comment: The solution there is VERY elaborate

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't obvious to me that it was the same question. It looked like a different question to me. I figured mine was more of a direct question. That seemed to be asking more than I was.

Comment: @masenkablast - what makes the solution there elaborate is also what makes it more efficient. Using expressions allows it to be translated to SQL rather than having to materialize the query then apply the predicate to the results.  In this case, I'd rather take the "performance hit" once (in writing the code) rather than every time I ran it.

Comment: @tvanfosson Learn something every day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that's the way to do it.  C# does not have a between operator I believe.

You could always cheat and write an extension method like I do:

```
public static bool BetweenDates (this DateTime checker, DateTime floor, DateTime ceiling)
{
    return (checker <= ceiling) && (checker >= floor);
}
```

Then you can do this ;-)

```
.Where(s => s.StopDateActual.BetweenDates(monthBeginDate, monthEndDate));
```

Comment: Nope, it has no between operator.

Comment: It wasn't that important. I just thought I may have been missing something. Glad to see I wasn't.

Answer (score 5):

You could do the following:

```
public bool Between(DateTime value, DateTime from, DateTime To) {
   return value > from && value < to;
}

where Between(a.StopDateActual, monthBeginDate, monthEndDate)
```

However, you should note that this works on `IEnumerable` and not on `IQueryable`, i.e. the results will be pulled from the data source before the where is applied. This could be a performance issue in the case of a large ammount of data, therefore, your where clasue is the best you can do ... just be careful with the > and < !!!