# Equivalent of SQL Between Statement Using Linq or a Lambda expression

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

Don't think this is a repost, difficult to search for the word between because it is used in everything (like searching for AND).

I want to filter a list based on a date range.

I have a list with some dates and I want to filter them by a date range.  Is there a Linq or Lambda equivalent of the `between` statement in SQL.

For example, the code below will not work in Linqpad (or Visual Studio):

```
void Main()
{
    List<ListExample> list = new List<ListExample>();

    list.Add(new ListExample("Name1","23 Aug 2010"));
    list.Add(new ListExample("Name2","23 Aug 2009"));

    var query = from l in list
        where l.DateValue between "01 Jan 2010" and "01 Jan 2011"
        select l;

}

public class ListExample
{

    public ListExample(string name, string dateValue)
    {
        Name = name;
        DateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateValue);
    }

    public string Name{get;set;}
    public DateTime DateValue{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var query = from l in list
            where l.DateValue >= new DateTime(2010, 1, 1) 
               && l.DateValue <= new DateTime(2011, 1, 1)
            select l;
```

You can write your own extension method:

```
public static bool IsBetween(this DateTime dt, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
   return dt >= start && dt <= end;    
}
```

In which case the query would look something like (method syntax for a change):

```
var start = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
var end = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
var query = list.Where(l => l.DateValue.IsBetween(start, end));
```

I see you've provided some samples with the dates as strings. I would *definitely* keep the parsing logic (`DateTime.ParseExact`or other) separate from the query, if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks I was having problems with the >= and needing to create a DateTime.  I find Linq a little confusing because they changed the syntax.

Comment: @Simon: Cheers. The `>=` doesn't have much to do with LINQ; it's an overloaded operator on `DateTime.` You can use `DateTime.CompareTo` or similar if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Ani - the DateTime.Parse was just for my example in LinqPad as I did not want to post a clients code onto the internet.

Comment: the only thing i've done is to change the extention function to stattic for global usage

Comment: How would you rewrite your extension method to support Linq to Entities?

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from l in list
        where new DateTime(1,1,2010) <= l.DateValue and DateValue <= new DateTime(1,1,2011)
        select l;
```

of course, normally warning about timezones and different times on clients and servers apply

Comment: Looks like the extension methods are not supported by Linq to Entities if I link to the entity framework.  Does this sound correct or am I missing something.

Comment: NotSupportedException: Method 'Boolean IsBetween(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.DateTime, System.DateTime, Boolean)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
Datetime DT1 = DateTime.Parse("01 Jan 2010");
Datetime DT2 = DateTime.Parse("01 Jan 2011");
var query = from l in list
            where l.DateValue >= DT1 && l.DateValue <= DT2
            select l;
```

in linq you use the && and || like you would in a normal boolean statement of C#.