# check the given date is present between fromdate to todate

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, datarowview

My dataset format looks like this

```
EMPNAME      FRMDATE      TODATE
ANU          01-10-2012   01-20-2012 
HARI         01-05-2012   02-05-2012
```

Now get input through a textbox as `01-17-2012` for a specific employee.

My question is: how to check whether the i/p date is between these two columns (FRMDATE,TODATE) in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DataRow []_dr= ds.Tables[0].Select( inputDate +">= FRMDATE AND "+inputDate +" <= TODATE");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method below will help you, for extra reading material on comparing dates have a look at these two threads:

[Using linq or lambda to compare dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087311/equivalent-of-sql-between-statement-using-linq-or-a-lambda-expression)

[Check if datetime instance falls in between other two datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672862/check-if-datetime-instance-falls-in-between-other-two-datetime-objects)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;


public bool IsDateInRange(string date, string employeeId)
{
    DateTime dateToCompare = DateTime.MinValue;
    bool isInRange = false;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(date) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeId) &&
        DateTime.TryParse(date, out dateToCompare))
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EmployeeDates WHERE EMPNAME = @EmpName";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", employeeId);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(table);

                DateTime fomDate = (DateTime)table.Rows[0]["FRMDATE"];
                DateTime toDate = (DateTime)table.Rows[0]["TODATE"];

                //DateTime.Ticks converts a date into long
                //Now you can simply compare whether the input date falls between the required range
                if (dateToCompare.Ticks >= fomDate.Ticks && dateToCompare.Ticks <= toDate.Ticks)
                {
                    isInRange = true;
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return isInRange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

db.ClubPorsant.Where(p => p.CreateDate>= _FromDate && p.CreateDate<= _ToDate).OrderByDescending(p => p.MablaghVariz).ThenByDescending(p => p.Shomarehesab).ToList();