# how to use between clause in windows phone azure storage.i want to get data in between two dates in windows phone

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

private async Task RunningData()
        {

// i want to get data in between two dates in windows phone using azure storage.

```
        var table = MobileService.GetTable<Tracing>();
        string date1 = "13/09/2014 12:58:42";
        string date2 = "12/09/2014 16:26:55";
        var items = await table
            .Where(Tracing => Tracing.Date == date1 || Tracing.Date==date2 )               
            .Take(PageSize)
            .Skip(this.currentIndex)
            .IncludeTotalCount()
            .ToListAsync();


        this.lstItems.ItemsSource = items;
        int totalCount = (int)((ITotalCountProvider)items).TotalCount;
        this.lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Showing items from position {0} to {1} (of {2})", currentIndex, currentIndex + PageSize - 1, totalCount);
    }
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087311/equivalent-of-sql-between-statement-using-linq-or-a-lambda-expression

Comment: that is related to mysql and here i want to know how to do do in .netframework

Comment: the selected answer on that question has a dot net extension method that you can use in your LINQ query. It's not mysql.

Comment: thats fine but i want exactly in microsoft azure storage.

Comment: Your question is not specific to Azure storage, you're asking a LINQ question--which is addressed by the question that @Jonathan posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method (thanks to [Equivalent of SQL Between Statement Using Linq or a Lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087311/equivalent-of-sql-between-statement-using-linq-or-a-lambda-expression)):

```
public static bool IsBetween(this DateTime dt, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
   return dt >= start && dt <= end;    
}
```

and then call it from your linq query:

```
var items = await table
        .Where(Tracing => Tracing.Date.IsBetween(date1, date2))               
        .Take(PageSize)
        .Skip(this.currentIndex)
        .IncludeTotalCount()
        .ToListAsync();
```