# Find a string value between 2 strings

Tags: c#, string, comparison

I have a database that I load with EntityFramework.

In this database there is a table that contains a couple of columns. 2 of those columns are called ZipcodeFrom and ZipcodeTill. The Zipcodes in the table are from different countries, so there is no real standard format.

The problem I have now is the following.

I receive a Zipcode and I need to find the row which contains the Zipcode range associated with the received Zipcode.

I can't use SQL to use the BETWEEN function. So I'm looking for a BETWEEN function for C# `if (Zipcode BETWEEN ZipcodeFrom and ZipcodeTill)`

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: How do you define what is in that range?

Comment: What have tried? Add sample code to your question.

Comment: rob, try this method from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087311/equivalent-of-sql-between-statement-using-linq-or-a-lambda-expression or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator?lq=1

Comment: You could get all the data from the database and use LINQ to do the searching.

Comment: @jonamreddy loading an entire zipcode database is not a good idea, typically - perhaps unless you're using a file based library

Comment: It really all depends on the format of the Zipcodes and when you define a Zipcode to be "between" two other zipcodes.

For example: a dutch zipcode consists of 4 numbers followed by two letters. Would 1234BC be between 1234BB and 1234 BD?
And would it be between 1234AC and 1234CC?

The best way in my opinion would be to treat a zipcode as a base-36 number and do your work based on that, but do all zipcodes follow a format where they are build up out of just numbers and letters?

Comment: i agree with nils above. it really is academic as to how you ascertain which zipcodes form a linear sequence that allows you to group and extract a subset that lies between two bounds...

Comment: As Nils O already stated. The data looks as followed: For NL we have 1234AA to 1234BB some zipcodes are only nummeric like the American zipcodes 6424 to 6427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this alphabetically, this effectively mimics a SQL `BETWEEN` operation:

```
var zipCode = "SOMECODE";

var result = from row in db.Table
             where row.ZipcodeFrom <= zipCode
             && row.ZipcodeTo >= zipCode;
```

If your provider doesn't support using `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` operators, you should be able to use [`string.Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
var result = from row in db.Table
             where string.Compare(row.ZipcodeFrom, zipCode) <= 0
             && string.Compare(row.ZipcodeTo, zipCode) >= 0;
```

Comment: The problem here is that when i do this the following error occurs because i'm comparing strings: Operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type string and string