# Why does my sql date comparison return 0 results

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

I apologize in advance if this question is too long but I wanted to make sure I included all the steps I followed to get to this point.

I have the following table in my SQL Server 2008 database:

```
CREATE TABLE [VSPRRecalc](
    [VSPRDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [CalcType] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_VSPRRecalc] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([VSPRDate] ASC)
```

It has some rows in it that look like this:

```
INSERT [vsprrecalc](VSPRDate,CalcType) VALUES('2010-12-15 10:17:49.5780000 -05:00','3')
INSERT [vsprrecalc](VSPRDate,CalcType) VALUES('2010-12-16 07:44:03.3750000 -05:00','1')
INSERT [vsprrecalc](VSPRDate,CalcType) VALUES('2010-12-17 07:40:40.1090000 -05:00','1')
INSERT [vsprrecalc](VSPRDate,CalcType) VALUES('2010-12-18 16:29:02.2203744 -05:00','2')
INSERT [vsprrecalc](VSPRDate,CalcType) VALUES('2010-12-20 09:58:50.1250000 -05:00','1')
INSERT [vsprrecalc](VSPRDate,CalcType) VALUES('2010-12-29 19:21:26.8120000 -05:00','1')
```

I'm using linq to check and see if a given date already exists in this table:

```
var recalc = (from re in VSPRRecalcs
              where re.VSPRDate.Date == oDate.Value.Date
              select re).SingleOrDefault();
```

Currently `recalc` returns null whenever the date is within 5 hours of midnight (like the 12-29 case in the insert statements above). I checked and the following sql is being executed:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[VSPRDate], [t0].[CalcType]
                     FROM [dbo].[VSPRRecalc] AS [t0]
                     WHERE 
                     CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[VSPRDate]) = @p0',N'@p0 datetime',@p0='2010-12-29'
```

Which returns 0 records. I modified the query to make the test easier to play with and came up with the following:

```
declare @t as date
set @t =  '2010-12-29'

select *, 
case  when  CONVERT(DATE, [VSPRDate]) = @t then 'true' else 'false' end  
from VSPRRecalc where 
CONVERT(DATE, [VSPRDate]) = @t
```

That query works for any other date in the table but not for any date that is within 5 hours of midnight (again see 12-29 above). If I run the above query without the where clause the 12-29 row does have 'true' displayed so clearly the boolean is evaluating the way I expect in the `select` statement but not in the `where` clause. Why does that happen?

Comment: Weird, the above `executesql` statement **works** for me (it returns 1 row)...

Comment: ... but, indeed, your last statement above is also not working for me (the `case` expression returns `true` for the 2010-12-29 row, but if I include the where part, no row is returned)!

Comment: Sorry that execute sql statement was left over from some testing I was doing. I've edited it now to reflect what should have been there. If you include the `and VSPRDate='2010-12-29 19:21:26.8120000 -05:00'` the query does work. I don't know what the difference is.

Comment: Don't forget about the SqlMethods class which allows you to run SQL functions like DateDiffDay(start, finish) == 0, *on the database*.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that's a bug on SQL Server, regarding conversion between the `DATETIMEOFFSET` time and the more "standard" types `DATETIME` and `DATE`...

What I have find out is the following:

**This** works:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[VSPRDate], [t0].[CalcType]
                     FROM [dbo].[VSPRRecalc] AS [t0]
                     WHERE [t0].[VSPRDate] = @p0',

                     N'@p0 DATETIMEOFFSET(7)',
                     @p0 = '2010-12-29 19:21:26.8120000 -05:00'
```

Which means that when we keep using `DATETIMEOFFSET`, there is no problem whatsoever... Still, you seem to need to find all records in a given day, not search for an exact `DATETIMEOFFSET`, right?

So, probably a little bit more useful, **this** works also:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[VSPRDate], [t0].[CalcType]
                 FROM [dbo].[VSPRRecalc] AS [t0]
                 WHERE [t0].[VSPRDate] BETWEEN @p0 AND @p1',

                 N'@p0 DATETIMEOFFSET, @p1 DATETIMEOFFSET',
                 @p0 = '2010-12-29 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00',
                 @p1 = '2010-12-30 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00'
```

I guess the secret here is keep using the `DATETIMEOFFSET` data type (and it's CLR equivalent, [System.DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx)). That way you will not get into this conversion issue...

(And, by the way, you should use a `BETWEEN` for searching records based on a date anyway. This allows the DBMS to use an index over that column, which is not possible when your `WHERE` clause is making a function call or a hard-coded conversion).

**Edit** I forgot there is no `BETWEEN` operator available for Linq for SQL - but that's easy to fix, just use something like `WHERE [t0].[VSPRDate] >= @p0 AND [t0].[VSPRDate] <= @p1'`... Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635) SO question is about declaring an extension method in order to implement it, but I don't know if it works...

Comment: I changed the Linq to be `VSPRDate >= oDate.Date && VSPRDate < oDate.Date.AddDays(1)`. This seems to work.