# Best way to find values in range

Tags: c#

I have a collection of values:

- [0-20] = 1
- [21-30] = 2
- [31-40] = 3 etc.

I expect input from users in the for of [44] for example. What would be the most eloquent way to determine in which item the value falls?

I can write a switch statement to match a case > < or an if...statement but neither of these in my opinion is eloquent enough.

**Update**

I'm looking for a neat and tidy way of finding the range in which my user's input fall, using something like LAMDBA for example:

```
List<int>().Find(x => x.WithinRange(range))
```

Or something like that.

Comment: im not sure what you are looking for...

Comment: Are you saying you have a collection of "Min/Max" values?

Comment: `if` statements are fine: simple, effective and understandable.

Comment: @CodingGorilla yes, I have min/max values

Comment: Do you need speed? If so, then a massive dictionary would be the fastest way, anyhow I do not see a good reason to waste so much memory and make code harder to read for such a little performance gain

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator

Comment: Is this meant to follow a pattern of going up in 10s where you say "etc."?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this as an extension:

```
public static int WithinRange(this int value)
{
    if (value < 0) return 0;
    if (value < 21) return 1;
    return (value - 1) / 10;
}
```

---

without `if` statements

```
public static int WithinRange(this int value)
{
    return (value < 0) ? 0 
        : (value < 21) ? 1 
        : (value - 1) / 10;
}
```

---

usage:

```
collection.Find(x => x.WithinRange(range))
```

Comment: something like this, but without using IF statements :$

Comment: nothing wrong with if statements, i was just curious about other ways of finding a value within a given min / max range

Comment: not sure if you can avoid `if` statements since your first case of `0-20` doesn't fit the the other patterns

Answer (score 4):

If your ranges are consecutive, as in your example (i.e. there are no gaps), you can store their endpoints in an array, like this:

```
var endpoints = new[] {20, 30, 40, 60, 90};
```

Note that the endpoints are sorted. You can now use a [binary search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to find the insertion point of 44 in this array, which is 3, will be returned (binary search will return bitwise complement of 3; you'd need to apply `~` to get the actual value).

Answer (score 4):

There you go:

```
int GetRange(int value) 
{ 
    return (value > 30) ? 3 :
           (value > 20) ? 2 :
           (value > 0)  ? 1 :
           0;
}
```

No ifs!

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over the ranges and see if the value falls within the range...

```
var ranges = new[]
{
    Tuple.Create(0, 20),
    Tuple.Create(21, 30),
    Tuple.Create(31, 40),
    Tuple.Create(41, 50),
    // ...
};
var number = 44;
for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++)
{
    var range = ranges[i];
    if (number >= range.Item1 && number <= range.Item2)
    {
        var theIndex = i + 1;
        // do something with theIndex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just manipulate the inputs:

```
int input = //Whatever the input is
int index = (input-1)/10;
```

Assuming integer input, and that your array is indexed as indicated.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I know this is an overkill but it might give you some ideas. As I undestand, you already know how to solve this problem, but you are just looking for a "prettier" solution:

```
public class Range
{
    public int Left { get; set; }   
    public int Right { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Range(int left, int right, string title) { Left = left; Right = right; Title = title; }

    public bool Contains(int x) { return Left <= x && x <= Right; }
}

void Main()
{
    var x = 15;

    var ranges = new[] {
        new Range(0, 10, "A"),
        new Range(11, 20, "B")
    };

    var foo = ranges.Where(r => r.Contains(x)).Single();

    Console.Write(foo.Title);
}
```

**My previous suggestion**: `For` statement is ok but I prefer LINQ :)

```
var x = 15;

var ranges = new[] { Tuple.Create(0, 10), Tuple.Create(11, 20) };
var range = ranges.Where(r => r.Item1 <= x && r.Item2 >= x );

Console.Write(range.Item1);
Console.Write(range.Item2);
```

Comment: Tuples are 4.0 specific, should have mentioned I'm on a 3.5 project. But thanks for all the feedback guys, really appreciate the expertise on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Less efficient .NET 3.5 alternative variation of @Jeff Mercado's answer:

```
var ranges = new[]
{
    Enumerable.Range(0, 20),
    Enumerable.Range(21, 30),
    Enumerable.Range(31, 40),
    Enumerable.Range(41, 50),
    // ...
};
var number = 44;
for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++)
{
    var range = ranges[i];
    if (range.Contains(number))
    {
        var theIndex = i + 1;
        // do something with theIndex
    }
}
```