# Is it possible to implement ExpressionTree.GreaterThan, etc for string so that LINQ can use it

Tags: c#, linq

I saw a question this morning ([Query my model on a range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896585/query-my-model-on-a-range-of-values)) that seems to be answered by (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1447926/195550), but the whole situation there peeked my interest in a more generalized solution.

I was hoping to be able to use Jon Skeet's answer to implement a `Between`that would work with string keys in a non-SQL generated environment, but it appears that the fact that string does not implement the **GreaterThan**, **LessThan**, **GreaterThanOrEqual**, **LessThanOrEqual** operators gets in the way of Linq being able to build the Expression trees necessary to do this.

- I realize that it is possible to just do query using the the `CompareTo` methods to accomplish this task, but I really like the elegance of the `query.Between(v=>v.StringKey, "abc", "hjk")` expression.
- I've looked through the System.Linq.Expression assembly, and saw that it is looking for a method named 'op_GreaterThan', for example for the GreaterThan operation, but *I don't know*

  1. Whether I can implement this for a string (knowing that I can't extend the actual '>' operator for strings)
  2. How to get the correct method signature built.
- I created the following example and tests that shows where the Between extension method doesn't work on a string key.

It would be quite elegant if that could be implemented for string keys.  Anybody have any suggestions, or insights on how to accomplish this?

**Between operator from Jon Skeet, with inclusive flag added**

---

```
public static class BetweenExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> Between<TSource, TKey>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
        TKey low,
        TKey high,
        bool inclusive = true) where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
    {
        var key = Expression.Invoke(keySelector, keySelector.Parameters.ToArray());

        var lowerBound = (inclusive)
                  ? Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(key, Expression.Constant(low))
                  : Expression.GreaterThan(key, Expression.Constant(low));

        var upperBound = (inclusive)
                  ? Expression.LessThanOrEqual(key, Expression.Constant(high))
                  : Expression.LessThan(key, Expression.Constant(high));

        var and = Expression.AndAlso(lowerBound, upperBound);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
                        and, keySelector.Parameters);

        return source.Where(lambda);
    }
}
```

**Working Test of the above using an "int" key**

---

```
[TestFixture]
public class BetweenIntTests
{
    public class SampleEntityInt
    {
        public int SampleSearchKey { get; set; }
    }

    private IQueryable<SampleEntityInt> BuildSampleEntityInt(params int[] values)
    {
        return values.Select(
               value => 
               new SampleEntityInt() { SampleSearchKey = value }).AsQueryable();
    }

    [Test]
    public void BetweenIntInclusive()
    {
        var sampleData = BuildSampleEntityInt(1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15);
        var query = sampleData.Between(s => s.SampleSearchKey, 3, 10);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, query.Count());
    }

    [Test]
    public void BetweenIntNotInclusive()
    {
        var sampleData = BuildSampleEntityInt(1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15);
        var query = sampleData.Between(s => s.SampleSearchKey, 2, 11, false);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, query.Count());
    }
}
```

**Non Working Test of the above using a "string" key**

---

```
[TestFixture]
public class BetweenStringsTests
{

    public class SampleEntityString
    {
        public string SampleSearchKey { get; set; }
    }

    private IQueryable<SampleEntityString> BuildSampleEntityString(params int[] values)
    {
        return values.Select(
               value =>
               new SampleEntityString() {SampleSearchKey = value.ToString() }).AsQueryable();
    }

    [Test]
    public void BetweenStringInclusive()
    {
        var sampleData = BuildSampleEntityString(1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15);
        var query = sampleData.Between(s => s.SampleSearchKey, "3", "10");
        Assert.AreEqual(2, query.Count());
    }

    [Test]
    public void BetweenStringNotInclusive()
    {
        var sampleData = BuildSampleEntityString(1, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15);
        var query = sampleData.Between(s => s.SampleSearchKey, "2", "11", false);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, query.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just modify the `Between` method to handle strings as a special case (and invoke `CompareTo` instead of the greater-than/less-than operators)?

Comment: I would have a special-case based on typeof(TKey)==typeof(string) and use CompareTo. Or frankly you could manually check for the operators, and then check for a CompareTo for a more generic solution

Answer (score 3):

You have to invoke the `string.CompareTo` method as part of the expression tree. You can then test its result. To see how that might look like, look at the following value in the debugger:

```
Expression<<Func<string, bool>> filter = str => str.CompareTo("abc") > 0;
```

Comment: I understand what your example statement is saying and thought I might be able to do something like `Expression<<Func<string, int>> lowCheck = str => str.CompareTo(low);` to get an expression that I could then run through the GreaterThan check, but that gave me an error that GreaterThan is not implemented for Expression<<Func<string, int>> -- obviously, but my brain is missing the link to success.  Could you possibly elaborate on what you were suggesting?

Comment: You have to pick `lowCheck` apart and drill down to the `CompareTo` call. Right now it seems you try to use the entire `lowCheck` which is much more than just the method call - it is an entire function including parameters (and different parameters!). The best approach is to create the method call directly using `Expression.Call`.