# Convert Webpage into PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have view name create on `HTTP post`, I want to convert that page into PDF when user click on the convert button, How to perform that, It call create action again and again wherever am click on convert button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query Style :

```
var results = from m in Model.Journals
where m.VoucherDate=> Model.BeginDate && m.VoucherDate <= Model.EndDate
select m;
```

Method style

```
var results = Model.Journals.Where(x => 
    x.VoucherDate >= Model.BeginDate && 
    x.VoucherDate <= Model.EndDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you wish to do something like this?

```
Model.Journals.Where(x => 
    x.VoucherDate >= Model.BeginDate && 
    x.VoucherDate <= Model.EndDate);
```