# LINQ How to make a BETWEEN condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model for handling score calculation based on different rules

```
    Scoremaster
    ----------
    Grade 
    MinScore
    MaxScore
    GradeRule
```

Some sample data is presented here

```
    A1 4.5 5     5
    A2 4   4.5   5
    B1 3.5 4     5
    B2 3   3.5   5
    C  0   3     5
    A1 8   10    10
    A2 6   8     10
    B1 5   6     10
    C  0   5     10
    A1 16  20    20
    A2 12  16    20
    B1 8   12    20
    C  0   8     20
```

The algorithm i am planning is like this

```
string FindGrade(double score,string rule)
{

 List<Scoremaster> scores=(from p in dbcontext.Scoremasters
                             where p.GradeRule==rule
                             select p).ToList();

//how can i check the score input of the function belongs to which category from this list using Linq

//example   FindGrade(3,5) = B2  FindGrade(4,5) = A2
//example   FindGrade(7,10) = A2  FindGrade(4,10) = C
//example   FindGrade(17,20) = A1  FindGrade(10,20) = B1                             
}
```

based on the input i can filter to specifica grade category. next step is to detect the score is in which range based on the properties minScore and MaxScore and then return the corresponding Grade and i am struggling to do that using Linq

Comment: Why not use `&&` operator with the `minscore` ? `where p.GradeRule==rule && (score => p.MinScore  && score  <= p.Maxscore)`

Comment: And if you want the full implementation of the `between` [here is Jon Skeet's implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like below:

```
string FindGrade(double score,string rule)
{  
    List<Scoremaster> scores = (from p in dbcontext.Scoremasters
                         where p.GradeRule==rule && score>= p.MinScore && score<= p.MaxScore
                         select p).ToList();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

***Try This***

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public IQueryable<T> FindMinimum<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,string rule)
        where T : YourEntityType
    {
        return source.Where(p => p.GradeRule==rule && score>= p.MinScore && score<= p.MaxScore);
    }
}
```

Usage Like this

```
var scores= db.myTable.FindMinimum("rule").ToList();
```