# NHibernate Linq use Between clause on IQueryable

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, nhibernate

I want to read records from an **ENTITY** where field **VarCharDate** is **Between** two user input dates.
If I execute the sql directly it returns successfully all the records between two date.

i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM ENTITY WHERE VarCharDate BETWEEN '2010-09-01' AND '2012-08-01'
```

Here the VarCharDate field is of type VARCHAR that is predefined and I can't change it to DateTime.
The Date Format is fixed to **'YYYY-MM-DD'** for storing values in this field.

**The Problem:**

EDIT:
I am using FluentNhibernate for Mapping entities. Also I build the schema on application startup by configuration.

I am using Nhibernate Linq for retrieving records in my C# application.
I tried something like:

```
session.Query<ENTITY>()
            .Where(e=> 
               Convert.ToDateTime(e.VarCharDate) >= Convert.ToDateTime(loInputDateString) &&
               Convert.ToDateTime(e.VarCharDate) <= Convert.ToDateTime(hiInputDateString)
             ).ToList();
```

Executing above statement results in runtime error NotSupportedException.

Google shows result regarding ExtensionMethods and I found it all confusing so unable to implement it yet.

How could I achieve something like:

```
session.Query<ENTITY>(e=> e.VarCharDate.Between(loInputDateString,hiInputDateString)).ToList();
```

I also tried something mentioned in the link
[LINQ Between Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447635/linq-between-operator)

But it's not working though.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned how you mapped your entities(HBM, FluentNHibernate, ...). But you can use a TypeConverter. If its possible to change the VarCharDate Property definition on your class, then change it to DateTime and let NHibernate convert it from string to DateTime and back.

Comment: Hi Rabban, Have updated the question also want to mention that I am using FluentNhibernate for Mapping Entities.

Comment: Did you tried it with a TypeConverter or do you want to stay with the Between extension? And can you change the Property (not the field) to a DateTime?